# Vista startup performance

Tags: windows-vista, performance, boot

After 2 years my Vista (32-bit) machine now boots quite slowly.

The event viewer tells me two programs comming up slow: explorer.exe and svchost.exe.

Fine. But what can i do that these programs comes up as quickly as before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could try to investigate individual programs, and while there are measures to 'invigorate' your PC that can help, periodically it can be worthwhile re-building your machine; that is, re-installing Windows and then restoring your personal data from backup.

I probably average a rebuild around once a year, but then again, I am a techie...

Comment: i'm a techie too, i have no problem to rebuild. But as this happens instantly i wanted to know if there is known issue.